# requests form Recaptcha

Tags: python, json, python-requests, recaptcha

I'm building a bot, but i'm blocked with the recaptcha.
I follow this website to verify that I'm not a bot: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

But I can't manage to find what is the response and how to get it.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
importe json
import urllib

urlcaptcha = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
secret-captcha = '6LdXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
params = urllib.urlencode({
    'secret': secret-captcha,
    'response': recaptchaResponse,
    'remote_ip': ip_addr,
})
# print params
data = urllib.urlopen(urlcaptcha, params).read()
result = json.loads(data)
success = result.get('success', None)

if success == True:
    print 'reCaptcha passed'
else:
    print 'recaptcha failed'
```

I can add more info if needed.

Comment: So you want instructions on how to write a bot that defeats anti-bot measures? Why?

Comment: I want to fill a form that has a captcha underneath.

Comment: Are you seriously requesting help to defeat security which is specifically designed to prevent what you are doing? if there was a solution, do you think it would be wise to publicise it for criminals to exploit?

Comment: no i'm asking that if there is a response it opens a browser an the human behind does the captcha solver. you have no idea of what i'm doing. and a lot of requests form ask for captcha

Comment: I'm puzzled, though. How did you get the site's secret-captcha?